# What is the most eficient way to replace symbols in String with values from map?

Tags: java, string

The problem: there is a string and map, where key - symbol that must be replaced, and value - new symbol instead of replaced on.

Example, let's suppose there is a string `One, two, three, four`. And I need to replace `f` with `+` and `w` with `-` etc, to get `One, t-o, three, +our`

How to do it in the most efficient way? I found only one solution - to iterate map and for every map entry to use `string.replaceAll(k, v)`. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to create `StringBuilder` to build a new string and a `Map` with required matches.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str = "One, two, three, four";
    Map<Character, Character> map = Map.of('f', '+', 'w', '-');
    String res = replace(str, map);
    System.out.println(res);    // One, t-o, three, +our
}

public static String replace(String str, Map<Character, Character> map) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        buf.append(map.getOrDefault(str.charAt(i), str.charAt(i)));

    return buf.toString();
}
```